# Is there any need to use .Net Core Secret Management tool?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-security

.Net Core comes with a Secret Management tool to store secrets for development purposes. If I have understood documentation correctly, so there is no encryption involved and all is stored in plain text.

Now the question is, why would we use this relatively cumbersome approach if we can just read from `appsettings.secrets.json` files e.g. that is much easier to work with and see secrets and add it to .gitignore so that it never appears in the source control.

Are there any security problems that I have not thought about with using this easier approach?

P.S. I can only think of a danger with accidentally commiting secrets file, but it's not that easy unless you change your whole .gitignore file

Comment: What you describe is the same thing the tool does, only manual. It's *more* cumbersome than just calling a tool. You could automate it of course. At this point though you'd have rebuilt the secret management tool itself. As for accidentally commiting the secrets file, it's *very* easy - someone in the team is going to misspell it. Or place it in the wrong folder

Comment: Well it's easier to give a file to someone rather than running commands usually, since it's required on each new developers machine

Comment: Another concern is the *build* server. How wil the `.secrets.json` file be delivered there?

Comment: Yet another concern is that working through `.gitignore` bypasses the Configuration conventions. A common way to protect secrets in *production* is to use the key management servicew of your cloud provider or the data protection provider. The Secrets management tool fits right into that architecture and is essentially just another configuration provider. You can use different secrets just as you can use different config providers per environment. You'll have to manually move the `.secrets.json` file around though, and ... modify your code to look for it per environment

Comment: Giving the file to someone is actually *more* steps than using the tool. It requires more steps to use it correctly in the Configuration architecture. All those things are *options* though, you can easily combine them

Comment: For example, you could put a "secrets" file in a file share where only the team members have read access and share the location through *another* configuration provider, eg through environment variables. Or use the environment variables to pick different paths per environment (development, qa, build server etc). You could enable auditing on the file share to see who accesses the secrets file too. Or it could be a *database* that returns different secrets to different roles/environments. A Key management system is a cryptographically secured settings database after all

Comment: I see your point, but production environment is of no concern, since this way of loading secrets is only for development. It will be loaded by other means in production. Otherwise it seems you are right that it's easier to mishandle

Comment: You could also *replicate* some settings files. You could do that with etcd on Linux or file replication on Window. That's one way of delivering settings changes to multiple servers/containers too.

Comment: The primary concern is that sensitive data shouldn't use the same *distribution channels* as the code. That's why `.gitignore` isn't enough. You'd be using the very same channel and depend on correct handling of a `.gitignore` file that any user can modify. How sensitive is that data? If it contains the `sa` password for the development database, well don't use the `sa` account. Use a separate account with limited privileges, that's only meant to access that database. Losing that password probably isn't a big concern

Comment: On the other hand, if it contains API or account keys to your cloud dev/staging environment, oops. It may be a *staging* environment but someone could still use them to do start VMs, create accounts or steal data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I should put the comments in a single answer.

The primary concern is that sensitive data shouldn't use the same distribution channels as the code. That's why .gitignore isn't enough. You'd be using the very same channel and depend on correct handling of a .gitignore file that any user can modify. The possibility of a mistake will always be there.

Whether that's acceptable depends on the type of secrets. How sensitive is that data? If it contains the `sa` or `sys` password for the development database, well don't use that account. Use a separate account with limited privileges, that's only meant to access that database. Losing the password to a limited dev account probably isn't a big concern. Probably.

On the other hand, if it contains API or account keys to your cloud dev/staging environment, oops. It may be a staging environment but someone could still use them to do start VMs, create accounts or steal data.

The big advantage of the secrets tool is that it works inside the configuration architecture. To the application, it appears as just another config provider that can be used or not depending on eg an environment variable or command-line option.

It's not the *only* option either, just a convenient way of handling secrets, especially in a distributed or OSS development environment. There are other options too:

- In a corporate environment you could put a "secrets" file in a file share where only the team members have read access and share the location through another configuration provider, eg through environment variables. The file can be secured through a security group which means adding/removing access to it will be a lot easier than adding/removing access to individual files. You could enable auditing on the file share to see who accesses the secrets file too. That's something you can't do with `.gitignore`
- You could use the environment variables to pick different paths per environment (development, qa, build server etc).
- You could even use a database that returns different secrets to different roles/environments. A Key management system can be seen as a cryptographically secured settings database after all.
- You could also replicate some settings files. You could do that with etcd on Linux or file replication on Windows. That's one way of delivering settings changes to multiple servers/containers too.